# Projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space, projective-schemes

How can I prove that the two different construction of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ (as $Proj K[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ and by gluing copies of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$) agree?
And how can I prove that if $A$ is reduced also $Proj(A[x_1,...,x_n])$ is reduced?

Comment: It's pretty standard. You can find it in Mumford's red book and in Miyanishi's "Algebraic Geometry" for instance.